# Setting CRS : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas

I'm working with a naive geometry column imported from a `csv` file, like this:

```
      name       geometry                                           id  
1     Abubilla  (POLYGON ((424405.897979997 4584795.70258297, ...   83
28    Abubilla  (POLYGON ((428405.900406701 4584295.67145889, ...   83
29    Abubilla  (POLYGON ((428405.919365087 4586795.67527349, ...   83  
... ... ... ... ... ...
9808  Zarcero   (POLYGON ((424905.883573821 4582795.69571411, ...   40
9809  Zarcero   (POLYGON ((425405.880556747 4582295.69113956, ...   40  
9810  Zarcero   (POLYGON ((425405.888148001 4583295.69267462, ...   40
```

When I try to set the CRS by the `crs` function:

```
gdf.crs({'init': 'epsg:25831'})
```

it yields this error message:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Could it be that Python doesn't recognize the geometry?
Is there another way to set the coordinates system for this "naive geometry"?

Comment: Answers to this question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390492/runtimeerror-bno-arguments-in-initialization-list

Comment: Indeed the first answer worked it out. My mistake was to directly asign the `crs` to a variable through a function. I shoul state it as:
`gdf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:25831'}`
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390492/runtimeerror-bno-arguments-in-initialization-list) on Stackoverflow solved it.

The mistake was to directly assign the crs to a variable through a function. It should be stated as:

```
gdf.crs = 'EPSG:25831'
```

With older GeoPandas / pyproj (< 2.0) versions, you might need to do (but this syntax is deprecated with the latest versions):

```
gdf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:25831'}
```

(Paraphrased from comments by users TomazicM and Rodrigo Vargas)